# Why do i get parse error when i want to make an mysql insert with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have an sql insert and I recive the following error:

```
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''CR0001'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO coordonate (id_scooter,lat,longi,alt,ip,port,speed,nr_satelites,battery_lvl) VALUES 'CR0001' "
```

my code is:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO coordonate (id_scooter,lat,longi,alt,ip,port,speed,nr_satelites,battery_lvl) VALUES  ?  ";

      con.query(insert, [array[0],array[3],array[4],array[5],rinfo.address,rinfo.port,array[6],array[2],array[1]], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only passing in a single array. When you insert, it needs to be an array of arrays wrapped in an array, like this:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO coordonate (id_scooter,lat,longi,alt,ip,port,speed,nr_satelites,battery_lvl) VALUES  ?  ";

con.query(insert, [ [ [array[0],array[3],array[4],array[5],rinfo.address,rinfo.port,array[6],array[2],array[1]] ] ], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Notice the two extra `[` before and two extra `]` after your data in the query.

```
[ [ [array[0],array[3],array[4],array[5],rinfo.address,rinfo.port,array[6],array[2],array[1]] ] ]
```

As an alternative, if you want to only insert a single row, you could do something like this, and pass in a JSON object:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO coordonate SET ? ";

con.query(insert, { id_scooter: array[0], lat: array[3], longi: array[4], alt: array[5], ip: rinfo.address, port: rinfo.port, speed: array[6], nr_satelites: array[2], battery_lvl: array[1] }, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: now I get almost the same error  code: `'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''CR0001', '44.312799', '23.866338', '0', '89.33.44.124', 1572, '0', '0', '50'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO coordonate (id_scooter,lat,longi,alt,ip,port,speed,nr_satelites,battery_lvl) VALUES  'CR0001', '44.312799', '23.866338', '0', '89.33.44.124', 1572, '0', '0', '50'  "
}`

Comment: it worked as JSON object thank you, as double  [ ] it did not

Comment: Glad you got it working with JSON! Just curious with the other way. Can you try this? 
`var insert = "INSERT INTO coordonate (id_scooter,lat,longi,alt,ip,port,speed,nr_satelites,battery_lvl) VALUES  ?  ";

con.query(insert, [ [ [array[0],array[3],array[4],array[5],rinfo.address,rinfo.port,array[6],array[2],array[1]] ] ], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
});`

Comment: I updated the first solution. It actually needs to be an array of arrays wrapped in an array.